# My code inside the try block is not being executed in android. No other thread seems to explain this

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-studio

I have a code for server request through android. This is the snippet of my try block:

```
try{
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                Toast.makeText(context,jsonObject.length()+"i ran",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(jsonObject.length() != 0){
                    Log.v("happened", "2");
                    String dbname = jsonObject.getString("dbname");
                    String userloggedin = jsonObject.getString("userloggedin");
                    String username = jsonObject.getString("username");String password = jsonObject.getString("password");
                    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String dob = jsonObject.getString("dob"); String mobile = jsonObject.getString("mobile");
                    String imagelink = jsonObject.getString("imagelink");String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    String currency = jsonObject.getString("currency");String recentcount = jsonObject.getString("recentcount");
                    String lowoncashlevel = jsonObject.getString("lowoncashlevel");
                    returnedUser = new User(dbname,Boolean.getBoolean(userloggedin),username,password,name,dob,mobile,email,imagelink,country,currency,Integer.getInteger(recentcount),Integer.getInteger(lowoncashlevel));
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I know that the Toast would cause error because there's a progress dialog running in background too, but it doesn't, that's how i found out that the try block is the one where the issue is.

This is the class that has this method:

```
public class FetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,User> {

        User user;
        GetUserCallBack userCallBack;

        public FetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallBack userCallBack){
            this.user=user;
            this.userCallBack=userCallBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData2.php");

            User returnedUser = null;

            try{
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                Toast.makeText(context,jsonObject.length()+"i ran",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(jsonObject.length() != 0){
                    Log.v("happened", "2");
                    String dbname = jsonObject.getString("dbname");
                    String userloggedin = jsonObject.getString("userloggedin");
                    String username = jsonObject.getString("username");String password = jsonObject.getString("password");
                    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String dob = jsonObject.getString("dob"); String mobile = jsonObject.getString("mobile");
                    String imagelink = jsonObject.getString("imagelink");String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    String currency = jsonObject.getString("currency");String recentcount = jsonObject.getString("recentcount");
                    String lowoncashlevel = jsonObject.getString("lowoncashlevel");
                    returnedUser = new User(dbname,Boolean.getBoolean(userloggedin),username,password,name,dob,mobile,email,imagelink,country,currency,Integer.getInteger(recentcount),Integer.getInteger(lowoncashlevel));
//                    returnedUser = new User(jsonObject.getString("dbname"),Boolean.getBoolean(jsonObject.getString("userloggedin")),
//                            jsonObject.getString("username"),jsonObject.getString("password"),jsonObject.getString("name"),
//                            jsonObject.getString("dob"),jsonObject.getString("mobile"),jsonObject.getString("email"),
//                            jsonObject.getString("imagelink"),jsonObject.getString("country"),jsonObject.getString("currency"),
//                            Integer.getInteger(jsonObject.getString("recentcount")),Integer.getInteger(jsonObject.getString("lowoncashlevel")));
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return returnedUser;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallBack.done(returnedUser);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }
    }
```

The execute method is called from this public method:

```
public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user,GetUserCallBack userCallBack){
        progressDialog.show();
        new FetchUserDataAsyncTask(user,userCallBack).execute();
    }
```

Comment: The Toast will not run from the background thread and will throw an Exception. But since you are not reaching there, it looks like there is an error in the way you are calling the FetchUserDataAsyncTask class. Can you show the line of code where you are actually calling this? My guess is you are missing the execute() method when you intend to start this class

Comment: @Gogeta Yes i'm aware that toast will throw an exception. I put a toast just before the try block and it caused an error, so i deduced that the code just above the try block is being reached but try block remains untouched.
I'm adding the method call to question

Comment: Can you place breakpoint on the line new FetchUserDataAsyncTask(.....) and see if that line of code is being reached? Your try/catch statement seems to be fine at first glance. So it must be the call to start the AsyncTask that is not getting run.

Answer (score 1):

The question is way too broad to get a proper answer, but even if you do post all relevant parts of the code and your issue will be resolved, I think that the best you can take from this problem is that you MUST learn to use the debugger!

Using debugger in Android Studio is piece of cake, really.

If you add several breakpoints and run your app in debug mode, in just few minutes you'll be able to pinpoint the exact line that causes the issue and either resolve the problem yourself, or ask a more specific question.

Debugger tutorial: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

EDIT:

My guess is that the code is executed and the exception is thrown, but you just ignore it in your `catch` block (except for printing the stack trace), therefore it looks like there is no exception. Few points on that matter:

1. Never ever write `catch (Exception e)` - always write `catch` clauses for particular types of ecxeptions
2. Keep the code inside `try` to a minimum. In your case, there is really no need for all this code to be guarder by `try - catch` (or, at least not by single `try - catch` block)

Comment: i think my question is pretty narrowed down. i dont know what more narrowing down is needed. if u re-read the post u will find what i have asked for. i know where the problem is, i dont know the reason that's why i posted the question.

Comment: @JaiSaxena, if you're telling us that you think that the code isn't executed because you don't see toast/error then it is not narrowed down. In fact, it is very unprofessional. Narrowed down is: "execution stuck at line number X". You can take my advice, or not - it is up to you...

Comment: My code inside the try block isnt being executed. The variables are not being updated, toast isn't causing an error. the try block is my problem. How do i narrow it down anymore! The TRY BLOCK ISNT EXECUTING! I'm pretty confident it isn't becuase if i initialise returnedUser with a User() object the code works fine. THERE ARE NO ERRORS. NO EXCEPTIONS. The code inside try block JUST WOULDN'T EXECUTE. I'm reading the debugger link you just gave me but there's really no more relevant information i can provide related to this problem. Tell me if I'm still missing something

Comment: Use logging to knwo what method is calling after last. Did you try use `Log.d(tag,text);`?